# How to convert a HTTP header into another?

Tags: apache, http-headers

I use Apache as a proxy for Tomcat.

I have to extract a field from an incoming HTTP header and create a new header to send to proxied Tomcat. To be more specific:

- My Apache receives a LDAP DN value in a header, ie: `CN=Jeff Smith/OU=Sales/DC=Fabrikam/DC=COM`
- I need to extract the token `OU=Sales` and forward the value `Sales` into a new header

**Important:** the Tomcat app. is commercial and is not able to parse the first header. That's why I have to do that.

I googled around mod_rewrite and mod_header but now I'm running out of inspiration... Help is very welcome!

Comment: Can you add full http request header to your question?

Comment: @umka: ok, I'll try to improve info on incoming request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer to my question because today a colleague found a (great) solution.

Imagine that my incoming header is named `USER-DN` and I need to generate `SERVICE_NAME`
I will receive it as follow (in the HTTP request, with other HTTP headers):

```
...
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
USER-DN: CN=Jeff Smith/OU=Sales/DC=Fabrikam/DC=COM
...
```

To grab it and generate `SERVICE_NAME`, this is what we added to Apache conf:

```
SetEnvIf USER-DN ^.*/CN=.*/OU=([^/]+)/.* SVC_VALUE=$1
RequestHeader add SERVICE_NAME %{SVC_VALUE}e
```

Now the new header `SERVICE_NAME` is available in proxied requests.